# Converting a value within 16-bit color range to a UIColor

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors

I have a value in one number range and want to convert it to a number in the 16 bit color range - 65536 colors. How can I then use this value in the 65536 colour range to a UIColor?
I have a method to convert a hex value to a color, how does one convert an unsigned int to a hex value and would this be accurate?

What would be the best way to get a color from a value within the 65536 color range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[UIColor colorWithRed: (color>>11)/31.0 green: ((color>>5)&0x3F)/63.0 blue: (color&0x1F)/31.0 alpha: 1]
```

Layout of 16-bit colors ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_color#16-bit_high_color)):

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you, I will try it out. For the latest devices, would it be better to use 24 bit color range?

Comment: More is better :) If it's under your control, I would recommend switching to 24-bit.

Comment: @Helium3 there was a problem with factors - I have updated the answer.

Comment: I do not need to switch, I am trying to convert values in one range to values in a color range, and then to the hex value or use some technique to get a UIColor from this calculated color value in the target range. Its just a little tricky to create a UIColor from the calculated color integer.

Comment: Is there no way to get a color using an index in a colour range in objective-c? Possibly a CG function? I am looking, but cant find any.

Comment: What's wrong with my method? You want to convert 16-bit color into UIColor, right?

Comment: Your method is great, I am thinking that losing colours because the range is too small could cause an issue. I want to be able to calculate a value within the range used by iPhone 4 devices and newer. Converting the color index to a UIColor.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29322/discussion-between-mar0ux-and-helium3)